# Efficient python for loop using txt files

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

So, I'm working on a python project (I'm a beginner), but I'm having trouble comparing a list to words in a text file. It's for a program that should unscramble words.

```
your_chars = input("Input characters:")
complete_list = []
final_lst = []
for current in range(len(your_chars)):
    a = [i for i in your_chars]
    for y in range(current):
        a = [x + i for i in your_chars for x in a]
    complete_list = complete_list+a
with open("P:/words.txt", "r") as file:
    for i in complete_list
        for x in file:
            final_lst.append(x)
print(final_lst)
```

I think it should work, but obviously it's not very efficient (especially the last three lines), but I can't think of another way to write it.

Ex:

input: `yhe`

output: `hey`

Any tips?

Comment: What exactly is the `complete_list` doing here? It looks like you repeat the lines a large number of times.

Comment: You're iterating through the text file twice, and you never close the input file. Try `with open(..) as file` and `for line in file`.

Comment: The last nested loop iterates on `complete_liast`, but doesn't use `i`.  That just a purposeless repeat.

Comment: Can you add some sample data, input and expected output?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that can handle text-input with words of arbitrary length:

```
from collections import Counter

your_text = input('input characters')
with open('P:/words.txt', 'r') as infile:
    file_text = infile.read()

old_words = {
    str(sorted(Counter(w).items())): w
    for w in file_text.split()
}

for w in your_text.split():
    i = str(sorted(Counter(w).items()))
    if i in old_words:
        print(old_words[i])
```

It doesn't need to check each permutation of input characters; it matches when the count of letters in an input word is the same as one from your input file.

---

This was my 1st solution and works, but ***do not*** input a string with a word longer than 10 chars or it will crash your computer:

```
from itertools import permutations

perms_list = []
perms = []
matches = []
your_chars = input("input characters")
your_words = your_chars.split()

for word in your_words:
    perms_list.append([i for i in permutations(word)])
for word in perms_list:
    for perm in word:
        perms.append(''.join(list(perm)))

with open('P:/words.txt', 'r') as comparefile:
    file_contents = comparefile.read().split()
for permutation in perms:
    if permutation in file_contents:
        matches.append(permutation)
print(matches)
```

Comment: the issue i was having is comparing the contents of the string `complete_list` with the `words.txt` file. If a word occurred in both, they will be added to `final_list`, which will be printed to the console.

Comment: if `P:/words.txt` is really big, this might not be the most efficient way to go about it.

Comment: @BenjaminFasick - Tested it and working for me. Lmk if it is for you.

Comment: This is actually kind of an interesting problem. Going to write a better solution which won't crash python if you type in a super-long string, and that can handle a massive file.

Comment: Works for me! It seems like a pretty cool way to handle it, definitely exposed me to some new concepts, so thanks so much!!